# How to pull database file from physically connected android device

Tags: shell, sqlite, adb

I am trying to copy WeChat database file called EnMicroMsg.db so I can view it in SQLite browser.

With my Nexus 7 tablet rooted and physically connected, the usb debugging checked I ran the following commands on cmd: `adb devices` which confirmed that my devices is connected, `adb shell` to enter the shell mode, `su` command to gain root, `cd /data/data/com.tencent.mm/MicroMsg/ and ls to see the directories

```
root@flo:/data/data/com.tencent.mm/MicroMsg # ls
```

first among the list is

```
6bb3ed9fac8c14c96ab852ea8fc570db
```

Then I changed to the directory `6bb3ed9fac8c14c89ab852ea8fc570db`, and used `ls` command to list the directory content.

`root@flo:/data/data/com.tencent.mm/MicroMsg/6bb3ed9fac8c14c96ab852ea8fc570db #
ls`

I found it listed among the results.

```
CommonOneMicroMsg.db
CommonOneMicroMsg.db.ini
EnMicroMsg.db
EnMicroMsg.db.bak
EnMicroMsg.db.ini
IndexMicroMsg.db
SnsMicroMsg.db
```

Having confirmed that it is located there. I exited shell mode and then tried pulling it by typing

`C:\AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb pull /data/data/com.tencent.mm/MicroMsg/6bb
3ed9fac8c14c96ab852ea8fc570db/EnMicroMsg.db`

but the response I got was

```
remote object '/data/data/com.tencent.mm/MicroMsg/6bb3ed9fac8c14c96ab852ea8fc570
db/EnMicroMsg.db' does not exist
```

How do I pull this file?

Comment: there's a space before "EnMicroMsg.db" in your question; is that The Problem, or is it copy/pasta?

Comment: @Jeff that is typo error. As you can see in the image the space isn't there. I will correct it in the question

Comment: Please don't post images.  Instead copy and paste the text and format it with the `{}` button.  Images are not searchable, whereas text is. Images may disappear over time as the hosting services change.

Comment: `adb` is the UNIX debugger, initially written by Stephen Bourne and still in use on UNIX. I suspect, you refer to another program that accidentally uses the well known name adb, e.g. a google program. You could avoid confusion if you did clearly mention that you are not interested in the original. Thank you!

Comment: @schily I'm sorry but I do not understand what you mean by "you could avoid confusion if you did clearly mention that you are not interested in the original".

Comment: @e.kenny67 ignore schily - anything that reminds him that unix has changed in any way since the 1970s triggers various levels of prejudiced ranting from him (especially if the reminder is related to GNU or other GPL-licensed software).   For anyone else confused by schily's mini-rant: in the context of Android devices, `adb` is the `Android Debug Bridge`.  According to the man page, **adb allows one to interact with a connected Android device**

Comment: As mentioned by @garethTheRed,  get rid of the image and replace it with copy-pasted text.  BTW, your image (AFAICT) doesn't show that the `EnMicroMsg.db` file you want exists in that directory....it may well do, but you've shown no proof.  Please show the (text) output of `ls en*` in that directory.  Finally, I'm not sure if this is relevant here but it's worth remembering that unix (incl. android) filenames are **case-sensitive**.

Comment: @cas I've edited it with copy-pasted text. Thanks

Comment: most likely that directory is only accessible by the WeChat app and root.  same as `adb shell`, `adb pull` doesn't connect as root.  maybe this Q&A at stack overflow will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891597/copy-db-file-with-adb-pull-results-in-permission-denied-error  (in short, run `adb shell`, then `su` to root, copy the EnMicroMsg.db file to somewhere in /sdcard and make it readable by everyone with `chmod a+r /sdcard/path/to/EnMicroMsg.db`.  Remember to delete the file after you've `adb pull`-ed it if it contains confidential data)

Comment: @cas The answer provided by Andrew Sun in the stackoverflow link you provided worked for me. That is to install adbd insecure. Thanks

Comment: please write up what you did and post it as an answer.  then accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Andrew Sun's suggestion in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28781159/5008284), I installed *adbd Insecure* from Google Play.

The developer according to [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590)
explained that the app gives root access in adb shell and allows access to system files and directories through adb push/pull, which exactly solved my problem.

After installation I was able to execute the adb pull command successfully outside adb shell.